# Namespace With New Instance On Each Call

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create something similar to d3(ex: d3.select()) but much more simple and I need to have a new instance each time I call the namespace function.  Is this possible and/or am I approaching this wrong?

```
var dom = new function () {
     var Element = null;
     this.select = function (query) {
         Element =  document.querySelector(query);
         return this;
     };
     this.append = function (elem) {
         Element.append(elem);
         return this;
     };
};
```

Desired use

```
var bodyelement = dom.select("body");
var p = dom.select("p");
```

Comment: You're returning `this` from the methods. `This` is the "dom" object. There's currently no way of getting the "Element" object from outside "dom."

Comment: The idea was to have simple wrapper for dom objects.

Comment: Right. So you need a way of accessing the element itself, right? As you don't have one, the "desired use" code won't work as expected.

Comment: Is that not the problem? Do you mean that every time you call `dom` it should be a completely new instance? Maybe the "desired use" should demonstrate this not working.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to have the "dom" object a simple wrapper that had some short hand functions for simple dom operations on elements.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what it's used for; I think that's why I'm getting confused. You just want a way of creating a new `dom` wrapper each time you use `dom`, correct? See my second answer below.

Comment: I don't really need to have access the the element itself as the dom object would be directly modifying the dom element variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run some code each time you use the `dom` object. So if the `dom` object was a function, you could call it to get a new instance.

```js
var dom = function () {
     var Element = null;
     var newdom = {};   
     newdom.select = function (query) {
         Element =  document.querySelector(query);
         return this;
     };
     newdom.append = function (elem) {
         Element.append(elem);
         return this;
     };
     return newdom;
};

console.log(dom() === dom(), "(false means the instances are different)");
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dom = new function () {
     var Element = null;
     this.select = function (query) {
         Element =  document.querySelector(query);
         return this;
     };
     this.append = function (elem) {
         Element.append(elem);
         return this;
     };
     
     // add a way of accessing the resulting Element
     this.element = function() { return Element; }
};

console.log(dom.select("body").element());
console.log(dom.select("p").element());
```

```html
<p>blah</p>
```